# network card issues on ASUS N550JK with ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 14.04, laptop, hardware, ethernet

The network card (realtek gigabit ethernet) doesn't work, doesn't send or receive packets. There is an error message saying something about a transmit queue timeout. I'm including some output that may be relevant. I've tried pcie_aspm=off, rmmod+modprobe, but no clue.

Can somebody please help.

Thank you

Martin

```
 # uname -a
Linux astro 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 # cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"

 # smbios-sys-info
Libsmbios version: 2.2.28
Product Name: N550JK
Vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BIOS Version: N550JK.204

 # lspci -k -s 05:00.0
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 200f
Kernel driver in use: r8169

output from dmesg

[ 89.796072] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 89.796084] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 0 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:264 dev_watchdog+0x276/0x280()
[ 89.796086] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
[ 89.796087] Modules linked in: bnep rfcomm nls_iso8859_1 uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops rts5139(C) videobuf2_core hid_multitouch mcs7830 videodev usbnet asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec arc4 snd_hwdep snd_pcm x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_page_alloc ath9k snd_seq_midi ath9k_common snd_seq_midi_event kvm ath9k_hw snd_rawmidi ath snd_seq mac80211 snd_seq_device joydev snd_timer ath3k serio_raw btusb snd bluetooth cfg80211 lpc_ich mei_me mei soundcore parport_pc ppdev lp parport mac_hid dm_crypt usbhid hid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel nouveau aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul i915 glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd mxm_wmi i2c_algo_bit ttm psmouse ahci r8169 drm_kms_helper libahci drm mii wmi video
[ 89.796136] CPU: 7 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/7 Tainted: G C 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu
[ 89.796137] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. N550JK/N550JK, BIOS N550JK.204 01/23/2014
[ 89.796138] 0000000000000009 ffff88042efc3d98 ffffffff8171a214 ffff88042efc3de0
[ 89.796141] ffff88042efc3dd0 ffffffff810676bd 0000000000000000 ffff880412340000
[ 89.796144] ffff8804129b6480 0000000000000001 0000000000000007 ffff88042efc3e30
[ 89.796146] Call Trace:
[ 89.796148]  [] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[ 89.796156] [] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 89.796158] [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[ 89.796162] [] dev_watchdog+0x276/0x280
[ 89.796165] [] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x80/0x80
[ 89.796168] [] call_timer_fn+0x36/0x100
[ 89.796171] [] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x80/0x80
[ 89.796173] [] run_timer_softirq+0x1ef/0x2f0
[ 89.796176] [] __do_softirq+0xec/0x2c0
[ 89.796179] [] irq_exit+0x105/0x110
[ 89.796182] [] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x45/0x60
[ 89.796186] [] apic_timer_interrupt+0x6d/0x80
[ 89.796187]  [] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x52/0xc0
[ 89.796191] [] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0
[ 89.796196] [] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30
[ 89.796199] [] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290
[ 89.796202] [] start_secondary+0x218/0x2c0
[ 89.796204] ---[ end trace 215922eb1d7267b2 ]---
```